# Qemu STM32 Emulation

Tags: windows, stm32, qemu

I run stm32 blinky example on windows using Qemu plugins with eclipse. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zvbarf1CSGs&t=628s) I can see green led on and off also those **green on - off ***messages are printed on the console*****. But inside of example program, I could not find where "Led: Green on" - "Led: Green off" messages printed. Also I looked qemu sources but there are only binary sources and some json files describing stm devboards. I dont have any clue where these led messages are printed.
I want to simulate my custom board so I need to find those signals where they are printed.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The video references a non official qemu version.

Look at the the source of the fork:
https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/qemu/tree/xpack/hw/cortexm/stm32